# Coinbase Buy Endpoint With 3D Secure Payment Method

Tags: coinbase-api

When I query the Coinbase buy endpoint with an European user that has a 3D Secure debit card as their payment method, the order gets cancelled 15 minutes later.  I'm assuming there is some other step I need to do?  I've tried opening the html page below with the 'PaReq' as a parameter but it just hung.  Here's what is and example of what is returned from Coinbase when I hit the buy endpoint with a 3D Secure user:

```
{"requires_completion_step":true,
"secure3d_verification":{
"payload":[
{
"name":"PaReq",
"value":"sjkdfjaslkdfjkalsdjfklasjdlkfjlksdfj"
},
{
"name":"TermUrl",
"value":"https://www.coinbase.com/buy/secure3d_redirect"
}
],
"url":"https://secure7.arcot.com/acspage/cap?RID=ajsdfjkjsd"}}
```